# A formula for an expected value

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

We have a Markov chain with $X_0 = z$, the return time $\tau_z$ of the first time at which we return to $z$, and some other state $y$. A proof I'm reading states:

$$\operatorname{E}(\text{number of visits to $y$ before returning to $z$}) = \sum^\infty_{t=0}P(X_t = y,\ \tau_z > t)$$

I have no idea where this comes from. The only thing I can think of is some complicated approach using inclusion-exclusion to reduce the right hand side to $E(X)=\sum P(X \geq n)$, but I suspect I'm just missing something obvious since the book just drops the above formula without saying a word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just linearity of expectation – the expected number of visits to $y$ before returning to $z$ is the sum over all times of the expected numbers of such visits at that time, which are the probabilities of the state being at $y$ at that time and not yet having reached $z$.

Comment: Oh, so we're viewing the variable "n. of visits to $y$ before returning to $z$" as a sum of indicators $$\sum_{t=0}^\infty \textbf{1}_{\{X_t = y, \tau_z > t\}}$$ and then distributing the expectation over the sum?

Comment: @JackM: Exactly.